# Mostrar DIV de acordo com a id inserida no formulário

Tags: formulário, input, script

Tenho 3 DIV igual com 3 id diferente, a DIV 2 tem este id 'ID2', então queria que quando digitasse no formulário ID2 a DIV 2 ficasse visível e os outros ocultos.

```css
#ID1 {display:block;}     
#ID2 {display:none;}  
#ID3 {display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="ID1"><a href="#" target="_blank"> botão 1 </a></div>
<div id="ID2"><a href="#" target="_blank"> botão 2 </a></div>
<div id="ID3"><a href="#" target="_blank"> botão 3 </a></div>

<form autocomplete="off">
<span>digite o id</span>
<input id='subj' placeholder='digite aqui'/>
<input type='submit' value="Aplicar"/>
</form>
```

No caso o que digitar vai chamar o id correspondente e adicionar display:block;

Answer (score -4):

Você pode criar classes para {display:block} e {display:none}

e então utilizar os métodos de classList.<add, remove, toggle, etc>

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList